# Integrals over bounded intervals tend to zero

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable with $|f_n|\leq f$ a.e. for some $f\in L^1$. Assume for any bounded interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_I f_n dx=0$$

to prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n dx=0$.

So we should show
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\int_{(-m,m)} f_n dx=0$$
If we exchange the limits in the above expression then we obtain the result. So why is the exchange of limits justified?

Comment: Hint: $\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus(-m,m)} f dx$ can be made very small for $m$ big.

Comment: Ok, thanks it works... and the hint is true because by LDC we have $\int_{(-m,m)} f  \rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}} f$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.